# Chrome Extension : Function inside chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I've had a problem for a few days concerning a button inside a `.js` script which does not execute a function.

Here my code inside `popup.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="panier_container"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here my code inside `popup.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

//Message en provenance du background
if (msg.text === 'panier') {
var panier_container = document.getElementById("panier_container");
panier_container.innerHTML ="<button id=\"totoButton\"> Affiche TOTO    </button>";
 }   

});

//Fonction toto
function toto() {
    alert("toto");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.getElementById("totoButton").addEventListener("click", toto);
});
```

When I execute the code, I see the button inside the popup, but when I click on the button, nothing happens. For information `msg` comes from my `background.js`.

But if I write this code inside `popup.js` all is ok:

```
var panier_container = document.getElementById("panier_container");
panier_container.innerHTML ="<button id=\"totoButton\"> Affiche TOTO </button>";

//Fonction toto
function toto() {
    alert("toto");
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.getElementById("totoButton").addEventListener("click", toto);
});
```

With this code, I see the button, and when I click on it, I see `toto` (the function is executed).

Do you know why inside the loop `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {` the button does not execute the function `toto`?

Comment: Can you show the code that sends a message to the popup? That is, you haven't shown a `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` call anywhere, and it's important to know when and how you call it. If you don't call `sendMessage` anywhere, then it's totally excepted that your event listener never runs, because the event it's listening for (the sending of a message) never happens. If you do have a `sendMessage` call somewhere in your code that you haven't shown, it's not running during the time that the popup is open.

Comment: Uhm, simply attach a global click listener on document.body and check if event.target.id is totoButton.

Comment: Put the `function toto()` and the `addEventListener` calls **inside** the onMessage listener function. Otherwise they are called before the message is received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for popup.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {

//Fonction toto
function toto() {
    alert("toto");
}

//Message en provenance du background
if (msg.text === 'panier') {
var panier_container = document.getElementById("panier_container");
panier_container.innerHTML ="<button id=\"totoButton\"> Affiche TOTO    </button>";  //create the button
document.getElementById("totoButton").addEventListener("click", toto);  //attach listener to button just created.
 }   

});
```

Your code `document.getElementById("totoButton").addEventListener("click", toto);` was being called **before** the actual element existed, because the element was to be created after a message was received.